# BMC Blood Seer: sees DW as wolfpack or not?

Tags: werewolv.es

Does the Blood Seer see Direwolf as member of wolfpack or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember this from a game I played in the past. I was BMC and I went through the archives. I found that DW does show as wolfpack when I get a chance I'll find the game